# Unable to install carbon using pip?

Tags: python, pip, graphite

I am trying to install carbon on my local machine using pip However, seems like it does not work not sure what is wrong ? Error log attached below ? Can someone help ?

Link: http://graphite.wikidot.com/downloads

```
pip install carbon
```

Error:

```
Downloading/unpacking carbon
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_MARSHELL\carbon\setup.py) egg_info for package carbon

    package init file 'lib\twisted\plugins\__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 1: path 'conf/' cannot end with '/'

    warning: manifest_maker: MANIFEST.in, line 2: path 'distro/' cannot end with '/'

    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'conf\*.conf'
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): twisted in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from carbon)
Downloading/unpacking txamqp (from carbon)
  Downloading txAMQP-0.6.2.tar.gz
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_MARSHELL\txamqp\setup.py) egg_info for package txamqp

Downloading/unpacking zope.interface>=3.6.0 (from twisted->carbon)
  Running setup.py (path:c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_MARSHELL\zope.interface\setup.py) egg_info for package zope.interface

    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): setuptools in c:\python27\lib\site-packages (from zope.interface>=3.6.0->twisted->carbon)
Installing collected packages: carbon, txamqp, zope.interface
  Running setup.py install for carbon
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_MARSHELL\carbon\setup.py", line 44, in <module>
        **setup_kwargs
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup
        dist.run_commands()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 971, in run_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 38, in finalize_options
        orig.install.finalize_options(self)
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 353, in finalize_options
        'userbase', 'usersite')
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 504, in convert_paths
        setattr(self, attr, convert_path(getattr(self, attr)))
      File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\util.py", line 124, in convert_path
        raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname
    ValueError: path '/opt/graphite/lib' cannot be absolute
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\ibm_ad~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_MARSHELL\\carbon\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-ptjmmo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_MARSHELL\carbon\setup.py", line 44, in <module>

    **setup_kwargs

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\core.py", line 151, in setup

    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 953, in run_commands

    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 971, in run_command

    cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\cmd.py", line 109, in ensure_finalized

    self.finalize_options()

  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py", line 38, in finalize_options

    orig.install.finalize_options(self)

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 353, in finalize_options

    'userbase', 'usersite')

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\command\install.py", line 504, in convert_paths

    setattr(self, attr, convert_path(getattr(self, attr)))

  File "C:\Python27\lib\distutils\util.py", line 124, in convert_path

    raise ValueError, "path '%s' cannot be absolute" % pathname

ValueError: path '/opt/graphite/lib' cannot be absolute

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:\\users\\ibm_ad~1\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip_build_MARSHELL\\carbon\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip-ptjmmo-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in c:\users\ibm_ad~1\appdata\local\temp\pip_build_MARSHELL\carbon
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\IBM_ADMIN\pip\pip.log
```

Comment: This seems to be a problem with the package. You might want to ask the developers.

Comment: The `setup.cfg` file in the package has `prefix = /opt/graphite` in the `[install]` section. Looks like the devs only planned for installing on Linux (and possibly OS X) systems.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon) is the Github project, and the last change was only 12 days ago, so it looks like it's being actively maintained. I'd [open a new issue](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/issues) after searching to see if anyone else has mentioned it, and see if it's even possible to run on Windows...

Answer (score 2):

From http://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html:

> Basic Graphite requirements:
>
> - a UNIX-like Operating System

So Windows is not supported. Try with a virtual machine.